# Examples of visualization featuring comparisons between countries?

Tags: data-visualization

Other then gapminder.org, could you please direct me to any good examples (interactive or static) of visualizations that compare between countries?

Comment: This question would be of interest at http://gis.stackexchange.com because most of the examples will be maps.  A nice example (comparing GPD and GPD per capita) was quoted in a recent discussion of cartograms http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7406/664

Comment: Tableau Public also has some (non map) visualizations which compare data across countries. http://www.tableausoftware.com/public/gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't seen international examples, I think [InstantAtlas](http://www.instantatlas.com/) offers quite a lot of nice features that could be useful in your case:

[image]

[StatPlanet](http://www.sacmeq.org/statplanet/) might be another (free) option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like Visualizing data patterns with micromaps by daniel carr and linda pickle, specially the concept of linked micromaps, which is influenced by the idea of small multiples (Tufte) and the idea of dot - charts (Cleveland). I strong recommend to read it.